# How to update/add new property to array elements with values from the same element without cursor

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a huge dataset that needs to be updated quickly to reduce downtime for an application
**I would like for documents that have example structure**

```
{
    "_id" : "5ed4a65efdb46e0001dc37ab",
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            "oldProp" : "x"
        }, 
        {
            "oldProp" : "y"
        }
    ]
}
```

**to be updated to**

```
{
        "_id" : "5ed4a65efdb46e0001dc37ab",
        "arr" : [ 
            {
                "oldProp" : "x",
                "newProp" : "x"
            }, 
            {
                "oldProp" : "y",
                "newProp" : "y"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Without using cursor!**

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('someCollection').update({x: { $type:"array"}}, [
  {
    $set: {
      x: {
        $map: {
          input: "$x",
          as: "entry",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$entry",
              {
                newProp: "$$entry.oldProp"
                
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],false, true)
```